# Blaster Printer USB keeps changing

Tags: ip

We have a network of 6 workstations and a server. However we use a printer called Blaster Printer that we use to print of labels for posting. This printer is a USB connection that is plugged into workstation 003 for example. I have shared using Homegroup which isnt very good I know, but it was a rush.

Ok so one other computer can sometimes connect (006) and the rest cannot. Also the 003 computer with the blaster printer keeps changing the port now and again which stops it from working.

Has anyone any ideas why this may be happening and what I can do to resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running Windows on all computers?

Comment: @mtak Yes we are running windows 10 on all machines